# Postgresql can't make an insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is really annoying me, since it's a really simple catalog from a database but when I try to insert I get this error:

> ERROR:  array value must start with "{" or dimension information LINE
>   1: INSERT INTO "catDelegacion" (delegacion) VALUES ('someData')...
>                                                            ^
>   ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: array value must start with "{" or dimension information SQL
>   state: 22P02 Character: 50

this is my code:

```
INSERT INTO "catDelegacion" (delegacion) VALUES ('someData');
```

and the definition of my table:

```
CREATE TABLE "catDelegacion"
(
  id_delegacion serial NOT NULL,
  delegacion character varying[],
  CONSTRAINT "catDelegacion_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id_delegacion)
)
```

I really don't know where is the error, also tried:

```
  INSERT INTO "catDelegacion" (delegacion) VALUES ("someData");
```

Comment: So you read the error message and then tried inserting something that clearly isn't in the format it states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared `delegation` to be an array (of strings), not a string.  Try this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE catDelegacion (
  id_delegacion serial NOT NULL,
  delegacion character varying,
  CONSTRAINT catDelegacion_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_delegacion)
);

INSERT INTO catDelegacion(delegacion)
  VALUES ('someData');
```